# Why do we use $F=GMm/r^2$ when calculating the centripetal force of the moon around the Earth and not $g=GM/r^2$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, centripetal-force, moon

When we calculate the centripetal force of a satellite orbiting earth, we use $g=GM/r^2$, implying that gravitational force and centripetal force are the same. However, when calculating the centripetal force experienced by the Moon due to Earth's influence, we use $F=GMm/r^2$. Both the satellite and the moon are orbiting the same central mass, why do we consider the Moon's mass and not the satellite's when calculating centripetal force? I understand that the mass of the satellite will be minuscule if it was even considered, but I don't understand, mathematically, why the Moon can't be calculated using $g=GM/r^2$ if $F=mg$!

Comment: You can use either equation. As you said, they're equivalent.

Comment: You know $F=ma$, right?

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can. Both are one and the same.

$F_{moon}=m_{moon}g$

$F_{moon}=\frac{GMm_{moon}}{r^2}$